# How to create a Python Kivy project in PyCharm Using virtualenv?

Tags: kivy

I created a project in PyCharm, and created a dummy kivy main file, but I get the below error when I try to run the main file:

```
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code that is causing the error, but it looks like your Kivy installation is incomplete or incompatible. Try uninstalling it and then reinstalling it with: `pip install kivy[base]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.